# Does the following inequality for $H^s$ norm hold?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Assume $f(x,t):\Bbb{R}^d\times\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ is a nicely behaved function ,such that all the expression below is well defined.Does the inequality for $H^s$ norm holds

$$\|\int_0^tf(x,y)dy\|_{H^s_x(\Bbb{R}^d)}\le \int_0^t\|f(x,y)\|_{H^s_x(\Bbb{R}^d)}dy$$

This seems to be Minkovski inequality correct?

Where $H^s$ norm is defined to be $$\int|\hat{f}(\omega)|^2(1+|\omega|^{2s})d\omega = \|f\|_{H^s}$$

Maybe I need to use Holder inequality?But I find it is fractional order.If we view $H^s$ norm as absolute value,then it's triangle inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\left(\int^t_0 f(x, \tau)\ d\tau \right) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-ix\cdot \xi}\int^t_0 f(x, \tau)\ d\tau=\int^t_0 \hat f(\xi, \tau)\ d\tau
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\left\|\int^t_0 f(x, \tau)\ d\tau \right\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}
:=&\ \left\|\int^t_0 \langle\xi\rangle^s\hat f(\xi, \tau)\ d\tau \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le \int^t_0 \left\|\langle\xi\rangle^s\hat f(\xi, \tau)\ \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}d\tau \\
=&\ \int^t_0 \|f(\cdot, \tau)\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}\ d\tau 
\end{align}
where the inequality is due to Minkowski.

**Edit:** If you worry about interchanging any integrals you may assume $f$ is Schwartz and use a density argument to get the desired result.